# Where can I find information about the geographical and network distribution of Solana's validator set?

Tags: validator, decentralization

I want to be able to see information regarding the ASN/DC/geographical decentralization of the Solana network and know how many validators run on AWS, Hetzner, and other providers, and how much stake weight is present at these. Knowing this can help me infer whether the network is at risk of halting if over 33% of validators by stake weight were to go offline at one of these DCs/ASNs. As a validator, I want to help make the network more robust to these types of scenarios and improve geographical dispersion of the network, so I would prefer to set up my validator somewhere less concentrated.

Comment: please elaborate the description with some reasons why one might want to know this information. it will improve seo

Comment: Let me know if I can add more! Added a tiny bit more to the response as well

Answer (score 3):

You can find information regarding the number of validators and their stake weights at particular DCs/ASNs  here: https://www.validators.app/data-centers?locale=en&network=mainnet. Improving network decentralization is very important and any help in this effort is highly appreciated by the community at large.